# ClassCastException while using ORC file format with Hive when vectorized.execution.enabled

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a hive table with following properties -

- ORC Storage Format
- transactional = true
- Partitioned on 4 keys - year, month, day, hour
- bucketed by **groupingKey**

I am using Hive Streaming for populating data directly into table.

Now my problem is - I am trying to run following query

```
select count(*) from table_name;
```

I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct$OrcStructInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedBatchUtil.setVector(VectorizedBatchUtil.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedBatchUtil.acidAddRowToBatch(VectorizedBatchUtil.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.VectorizedOrcAcidRowReader.next(VectorizedOrcAcidRowReader.java:82)
```

However if I turn off vectorized execution by setting following property

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = false;
```

everything works fine (Although it takes ages to complete).

Why is this happening ? From what I understand, with ORC format, vectorized execution should work.

**Hadoop Version** - 2.7.1

**Hive Version** - 1.2.1

Comment: Rishabh, My answer was useful?

Comment: @RamPrasadG I am using hive 1.2.1 and trying to see if I can upgrade to 1.3.0. Hence unable to verify this. However, it seems it is the same issue. Thanks a lot. Will verify and accept answer

Comment: if you are okay with answer please vote/accept as owner

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this hive issue has been closed/fixed. please recheck your version of hive used.

Please check [Vectorized execution causes ClassCastException](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12795)

[image]